# How to select text in terminal? (linux mint)

Tags: bash, terminal, linux-mint

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and the cursor changes but what do I have to press afterwards? ( tried <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> and so on)

Comment: Are you talking about an X terminal or about the TTY console? If it's an X terminal you can simply select it with your mouse. In a TTY, selecting doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @DaniloBargen being the linux newbie that i am i can only tell you that the name of the software is MATE Terminal 1.2.1. If it's not too much to ask could you also explain the diff between x terminal and tty console?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to copy is to use your mouse. Highlight the text you are interested in and then use middle click to paste.

Alternatively, if you are using `gnome-terminal`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but i'm interested in finding the hotkeys for this one.

Comment: Hot keys for what? Copy all? Copy specific text? Why don't you just redirect the output of the command you want to use `ls >ls.txt`? Wha exactly is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: well i'm looking to paste and copy between VMs. I know i could use the mouse, it just bugs me that i don't know how to select text in the terminal window using just the keyboard ( don't know why i'm so obssesed with it :) ).As said in the question, somebody mentioned using ctrl + a to enter select mode and then use arrows to select the text but it does not work. It's a matter of "can it be done using just the keyboard?". And it also helps when i disable the touchpad on my laptop- i tend to click other windows accidentally when typing and it disrupts my workflow)

Comment: The thing is, this depends on the terminal emulator you are using. I don't know of any terminal emulator that has a select all shortcut because, frankly, it is not very useful. All you need to do is select with the mouse or redirect the output to a file. Anyway a shortcut might exist in some terminal emulator or other. Look around, see if you can feed your obsession :).

Comment: Well thanks anyway. And i wasn't talking of a select all feature. Just plain select

Comment: Well, how can you select without specifying _what_ you want to select? It sounds like you want to treat terminal output as a normal text file, it isn't. If you mean copying text you have written but not executed, Ctrl+K will copy.

Comment: ctrl+k does not work. just tried it. worte something in terminal window then tried a paste in a text editor

Comment: It will cut everything after the current position of your cursor. You can use Ctrl+W to cut the previous word and Alt+D to cut the next one. In all cases Ctrl+Y pastes it back. You will have trouble sharing a clipboard between the VMS though unless you use the window manager's clipboard by explicitly selecting text with the mouse.

Comment: ctrl +a -> ctrl + k -> ctrl + y works..kinda.   You will have trouble sharing a clipboard between the VMS though unless you use the window manager's clipboard by explicitly selecting text with the mouse - too bad.